# unsatisfied link error in android native call

Tags: android, android-ndk, jdi

I am trying to call a native function from an android activity class, which results in a unsatisfied link error. Here is the activity.

```
package com.example.rockboos;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public native void hello();
    private void boostMe() 
    {
        hello();
    }

    private VolumeController volumeController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.volumeController = new VolumeController(this);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //volumeController.boost();
                boostMe();




            }
        });
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hellomodule");

    }

}
```

native.h

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_rockboost_MainActivity_hello(JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

native.c:

```
#include "mp3gain/mp3gain.h"

#include "native.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_rockboost_MainActivity_hello(JNIEnv *jniEnv, jobject thiz)
{
    //changeGain("/sdcard0/test.mp3", 10, 10);
    int x = 0;
    x++;
}
```

catlogs

08-03 17:58:54.040: D/dalvikvm(4007): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-1/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c88e70

08-03 17:58:54.050: D/dalvikvm(4007): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-1/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c88e70

08-03 17:58:54.050: D/dalvikvm(4007): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-1/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c88e70, skipping init

08-03 17:58:55.700: D/gralloc_goldfish(4007): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-03 17:59:15.040: W/dalvikvm(4007): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/rockboost/MainActivity;.hello:()V

08-03 17:59:15.050: D/AndroidRuntime(4007): Shutting down VM
08-03 17:59:15.050: W/dalvikvm(4007): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a4ed70)

08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): Process: com.example.rockboost, PID: 4007

**08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.rockboost.MainActivity.hello:()V**

08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at 
com.example.rockboost.MainActivity.hello(Native Method)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at 
com.example.rockboost.MainActivity.boostMe(MainActivity.java:17)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.example.rockboost.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:15)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.example.rockboost.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4450)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18600)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-03 17:59:15.130: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 18:04:16.680: I/Process(4007): Sending signal. PID: 4007 SIG: 9
08-03 18:24:16.030: D/dalvikvm(5266): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-2/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c89f18
08-03 18:24:16.410: D/dalvikvm(5266): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-2/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c89f18
08-03 18:24:16.410: D/dalvikvm(5266): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-2/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c89f18, skipping init
08-03 18:24:17.330: D/gralloc_goldfish(5266): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

08-03 17:58:54.040: D/dalvikvm(4007): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-1/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c88e70
**08-03 17:58:54.050: D/dalvikvm(4007): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-1/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c88e70**
08-03 17:58:54.050: D/dalvikvm(4007): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.rockboost-1/libhellomodule.so 0xb1c88e70, skipping init
08-03 17:59:15.040: W/dalvikvm(4007): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/rockboost/MainActivity;.hello:()V

The library compiles. I can see in the logs that the shared library could be loaded.
However the native call didn't work and caused a unsatified link error

The naming convention seem fine as far as i can see. I can start the application the error only happens when calling the native function. I also made sure that the library is built for the correct cpu/architecture,

### Update

I ran objdump -t to check the symbol table:

```
$ objdump.exe -t libhellomodule.so

libhellomodule.so:     file format elf32-little

SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

So the function is not in the library but I don't know why.
Here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := hellomodule
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mp3gain mp3gain/mpglibDBL  

LOCAL_C_INCLUDE :=  mp3gain mp3gain/mpglibDBL native.h


APP_ABI := armeabi

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

There's probably something wrong with that but i'm not sure where.

### Update 2

Fixed my Android.mk and used another library

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mp3lame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bitstream.c fft.c id3tag.c mpglib_interface.c presets.c quantize.c reservoir.c tables.c util.c VbrTag.c encoder.c gain_analysis.c lame.c newmdct.c psymodel.c quantize_pvt.c set_get.c takehiro.c vbrquantize.c version.c native.c   


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Compiles fine but with the same result, program cannot find the function in the library. Altough nm shows that the symbol is there:

```
$ nm -D ../libs/armeabi/libmp3lame.so | grep hello
0001c4e9 T Java_com_example_rockboost_MainActivity_hello
```

Comment: Any chance the installed library is a "stale" one without your latest changes?  You might clean the project and re-deploy.  You can also use the ndk's objdump to make sure the function is really in the .so (possibly the one you can extract from the apk with zip file tools).

Comment: Open your APK as ZIP and extract the `libmp3lame.so` from there. Re-run **nm** for that file.

Answer (score 1):

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES` should be a list of C files. In your case, it seems to be

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = native.c
```

When you run `ndk-build`, you will see it compiled.

There are other mistakes in your **Android.mk**.

`APP_ABI` is irrelevant there; put it in **Application.mk** or on command line.

`LOCAL_C_INCLUDE` is misspelled; it reads **LOCAL_C_INCLUDES**. This lists *directories* where to look for header files. In your case, it may be path from your project to `mp3gain` directory.